# Differences in source code downloaded by R and source code in website

Tags: r, web-scraping, xml2

I am scraping a website extracting information about some product, but I have problems with prices. My code is the following:

```
> enlace<-"http://www.carulla.com/products/0000687608965009/Crema+Dental+Sensitive+Proalivio+Colgate"
> download.file(enlace, destfile = "scrapedpage.html", quiet=TRUE)
> doc<-read_html("scrapedpage.html")
> # description
> toString(xml_find_all(doc,xpath=paste0('//*[@id="pdpProduct"]/div[3]/h3')))
[1] "<h3 class=\"pdpInfoProductName\" itemprop=\"name\">Crema Dental Sensitive Proalivio Colgate</h3>"
> # reference
> toString(xml_find_all(doc,xpath=paste0('//*[@id="pdpProduct"]/div[3]/p')))
[1] "<p class=\"pdpInfoProductRef\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPresentación:C \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPLU:739983</p>"
> # prices
> toString(xml_find_all(doc,xpath=paste0('//*[@id="pdpProduct"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/h4')))
[1] ""
```

I checked this information in source code in the original page, where I find this:

```
<div class="pdpInfoProduct pull-left">
            <h3 class="pdpInfoProductName" itemprop="name">Crema Dental Sensitive Proalivio Colgate</h3>
            <h2 class="pdpInfoProductBrand" itemprop="brand">COLGATE</h2>
            <p class="pdpInfoProductRef">
                                Presentación:C&nbsp;
                                PLU:739983</p>
                        <div class="pdpInfoProductPrices">  
                <div class="pull-right">
                            <div class="pro-big-Ovalo">
                                <p>25%</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="pdpInfoProductPrice" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

                <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="COP" />
                    <meta itemprop="price" content="17213.0" />
                    <h4 class="priceOffer">
                        $17.213</h4>
                    <h6 class="before">Antes: <span class="strikeText">
                                $22.950</span>
                        </h6>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

My information of interest is $17.213, but when I try to download source code with R, I obtain the following:

```
> con2<-url(enlace,"r")
> x<-readLines(con2)
> close(con2)
> x[1270:1285]
 [1] "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPLU:739983</p>"                                                                                                                                                
 [2] "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"pdpInfoProductPrices\">\t"                                                                                                                           
 [3] "\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"pdpInfoProductPrice\" itemprop=\"offers\" itemscope itemtype=\"http://schema.org/Offer\">"                                                            
 [4] "\t\t\t\t\t"                                                                                                                                                                  
 [5] "\t\t\t\t\t<meta itemprop=\"priceCurrency\" content=\"COP\" />"                                                                                                               
 [6] "                        <meta itemprop=\"price\" content=\"\" />"                                                                                                       
 [7] "\t\t\t\t\t\t<h4 class=\"price\">"                                                                                                                                             
 [8] "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</h4>"                                                                                                                                                           
 [9] "\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>"                                                                                                                                                           
[10] "\t\t\t\t</div>"                                                                                                                                                             
[11] "\t\t\t\t"                                                                                                                                                                   
[12] "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"                                                                                                                                                              
[13] "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  <div class=\"product-seller row-fluid\">"                                                                                                                
[14] "\t\t\t\t       <!-- +++++ Carulla Seller +++++ -->                                                "                                                                         
[15] "                               <p> Vendido por: &nbsp Carulla</p>                                                                                                      "
[16] "                    </div>"
```

That is, I obtain \t\t\t\t\t\t\t instead of $17.213.

I will very grateful with your help.

Answer (score 0):

the website is probably checking the UA and cookies to try to prevent you from doing exactly what you're doing. i just tried downloading it with wget, and just flat-out got a 403 Forbidden error.

the idea of web-scraping is kind of obsolete nowadays, at least for commercial pages. there are some workarounds (for example, you can check the help for download.file(), and read the manpages for wget and curl to see how to change the UA and import cookies), but if you really want to do this at scale, you might want to look into browser scripting and then import that data into R.

keep in mind that you're doing something the site owners don't want you to be doing. in short, this has almost nothing to do with R.